# Deriving priority ranking from the existing rank and other additional lookup

Tags: sql, hive, apache-spark-sql, impala

I am trying to derive the `New expected_ranking_2` based on the existing `ranking_1` and `ct_1,ct_2, st_1,st_2 , co_1 ,co_2`.

Use case :

1. If `ct_1 == ct_2 AND st_1 == st_2 AND co_1 == co_2` then `Expected_ranking_2 = 1`
2. if `(ct_1 == ct_2 AND st_1 == st_2) OR (st_1 == st_2 AND co_1 == co_2) OR (ct_1 == ct_2 AND co_1 == co_2)` then `Expected_ranking_2 = 2`
3. if `ct_1 == ct_2 OR st_1 == st_2 OR co_1 == co_2` then `Expected_ranking_2 = 3` else it should taking `ranking_1 value`.

If the `expected_ranking_2` has duplicate then based on `ranking_1` value should be updated.

Sample data :

[image]

Below is the query I wrote but its not giving the `expected_ranking_2` and query is getting complicated and hence looking for some suggestion on it.

```sql
WITH temp_tb AS
  (SELECT p.*,
          CASE
              WHEN (p.co_1 == p.co_2
                    AND p.st_1= p.st_2
                    AND p.ct_1 = p.ct_2) THEN 1
              WHEN ((p.co _1== p.co_2
                     AND p.st_1= p.st_2)
                    OR (p.co_1 == p.co_2
                        AND p.ct_1= p.ct_2)
                    OR (p.st_1= p.st_2
                        AND p.ct_1 = p.ct_2)) THEN 2
              WHEN ((p.co_1 == p.co_2
                     OR p.st_1= p.st_2
                     OR p.ct_1 = p.ct_2)) THEN 3
              ELSE ranking_1
          END AS lookup_temp
   FROM Table_x p),
     temp_tb_1 AS
  (SELECT q.*,
          LAG(q.lookup_temp, 1, 0) OVER(PARTITION BY q.id
                                        ORDER BY q.ranking_1, q.lookup_temp ASC) AS lag_priority
   FROM temp_tb q),
     temp_tb_2 AS
  (SELECT r.*,
          (r.lookup_temp - r.lag_priority) AS lag_priority_diff
   FROM temp_tb_1 r),
     temp_tb_3 AS
  (SELECT s.*,
          CASE
              WHEN s.lag_priority_diff=1 THEN s.lookup_temp
              ELSE s.ranking_1
          END AS Expected_ranking_2
   FROM temp_tb_2 s)
SELECT *
FROM temp_tb_3
```

Comment: Are you *sure* you're using SQL Server? `==` isn't a valid equality operator in T-SQL.

Comment: I am using SparkSQL

Comment: Please please ensure you tag correctly, @Raj ; that isn't the RDBMS you've tagged.